# Transit via uk with Italian Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, transit

I am Eritrean traveling from Sudan to Italy. I have got a Schengen  visa to Italy, my question is, can I transit through UK without any other additional visa, mean with that Italian schengen visa only.

Comment: It depends on what kind of Schengen visa you have.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. The United Kingdom is not part of the Schengen Agreement, and Eritreans have to apply for a direct airside transit visa (DATV). You can see the [requirements for a DATV](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-transit-airside/) at the Home Office website.